# javax.net.ssl.keyStore information

Tags: java, jboss

In jboss server, in which file we define to look the keystore certificates?
I'm facing errors and when saw the boot.log file, its taking some certificate which is not available in my server.

boot.log file:

```
DEBUG [ServerInfo]     javax.net.ssl.keyStore: C:/jboss/jboss-appserver/server/conf/clientCerts.jks
```

when boot.log file is generated, which file does it read??

Answer (score 0):

It's in the connector definition

```
<Connector 
       port="8443" minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="75"
       enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true" 
       acceptCount="100"  maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       SSLCertificateFile="/usr/local/ssl/server.crt" 
       SSLCertificateKeyFile="/usr/local/ssl/server.pem"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

see https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/ssl-howto.html